# Как получить google click id(gclid) или ссылку с которой пользователь установил приложение?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-adsense, google-adwords

У меня есть реклама в google adsense для android приложения и я знаю, что когда пользователь переходит по рекламе и устанавливает приложение, гугл дает ему уникальный идентификатор, для отслеживания его деятельности, как можно получить этот идентификатор или хотя бы ссылку по которой он пришел? 
Я уже пробовал получить через интент, и через google play install referrer, но интент возвращает нулл, а instal referrer пустые значения или "FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED" 
вот мой код для получения через интент:

```
    val intent = this.intent
    val uri = intent?.data
    urlFromIntent = uri.toString()
```

и Манифест:

```
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="false" />
```

А вот код для google play referrer:

```
     mRefferClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build()
    mRefferClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {

        @SuppressLint("SwitchIntDef")
        override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
            when (responseCode) {
                InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                    try {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("InstallReferrerState", "OK")
                        var response = mRefferClient.installReferrer
                        urlFromReferClient = response.installReferrer
                        urlFromReferClient += ";" + response.referrerClickTimestampSeconds
                        urlFromReferClient += ";" + response.installBeginTimestampSeconds
                        mRefferClient.endConnection()
                    } catch (e: RemoteException) {
                        urlFromReferClient = e.toString()
                    }
                }
                InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                    urlFromReferClient = "FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED"
            }
                InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                    urlFromReferClient = "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE"
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот такая же ситуация, перепробовал уже все способы. Дело в том что если ты переходишь по рекламе например из браузера Chrome то все ок - там `gclid` есть и получить его легко. Но если ты нашел свою рекламу в самом Play Market, ничего не приходит кроме `utm_source/utm_medium`.

Уже и в поддержку писал и перешерстил всю документаций - результата ноль.

Answer (score 3):

Я нашел решение, но оно частичное

```
fun getGCLID() {
    referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build()
    referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {

        override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
            when (responseCode) {
                // Get tracker.
                InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                    val response: ReferrerDetails = referrerClient.installReferrer
                    val referrer = response.installReferrer
                    Log.d("TagGCLID", "onInstallReferrerSetupFinished: 1 $referrer")
                    when {
                        "gclid%3D" in referrer -> {
                            var temp = referrer.substringAfter("gclid%3D")
                            var gclid = temp.split("&")
                            var gclidprecent = gclid[0].split("%")
                            customPreferences?.setString("gclid", gclidprecent[0])
                            customPreferences?.setString("src", "ad")
                            Log.d("TagGCLID", "gclid%3D is detected in referrer // is $temp")
                        }
                        "gclid%" in referrer -> {
                            var temp = referrer.substringAfter("gclid%")
                            var gclid = temp.split("&")
                            var gclidprecent = gclid[0].split("%")
                            customPreferences?.setString("gclid", gclidprecent[0])
                            customPreferences?.setString("src", "ad")
                            Log.d("TagGCLID", "gclid% is detected in referrer // is $temp")
                        }
                        "gclid=" in referrer -> {
                            var temp = referrer.substringAfter("gclid=")
                            var gclid = temp.split("&")
                            var gclidprecent = gclid[0].split("%")
                            customPreferences?.setString("gclid", gclidprecent[0])
                            customPreferences?.setString("src", "ad")
                            Log.d("TagGCLID", "GCLID is detected in referrer // is $temp")
                        }
                        "gclid" in referrer -> {
                            var temp = referrer.substringAfter("gclid")
                            var gclid = temp.split("&")
                            var gclidprecent = gclid[0].split("%")
                            customPreferences?.setString("gclid", gclidprecent[0])
                            customPreferences?.setString("src", "ad")
                            Log.d("TagGCLID", "GCLID is detected in referrer // is $temp")
                        }
                        else -> {
                            customPreferences?.setString("src", "organic")
                            customPreferences?.setString("gclid", "0")
                            Log.d(
                                    "TagGCLID",
                                    "no GCLID is detected in referrer\n" + "$referrer"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(
                            "TagGCLID", "sp value\n" +
                            "${customPreferences?.getString("gclid")}" +
                            "${customPreferences?.getString("src")}"
                    )
                    customPreferences?.setBoolean("is_first_time", true)
                    referrerClient.endConnection()
                }
                InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                    Log.d("TagGCLID", "InstallReferrerResponse: -1")
                    customPreferences?.setString("src", "organic")
                    customPreferences?.setString("gclid", "0")

                    // API not available on the current Play Store app.
                }
                InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                    Log.d("TagGCLID", "InstallReferrerResponse: -2")
                    customPreferences?.setString("src", "organic")
                    customPreferences?.setString("gclid", "0")

                    // Connection couldn't be established.
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
            Log.d("TagGCLID", "onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected: -3")
            customPreferences?.setString("src", "organic")
            customPreferences?.setString("gclid", "0")
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    })
}
```

Я могу получить GCLID только из рекламы которая находится в вебе (например, если я в гугле введу запрос на то, что бы мне кинуло примерно нужную мне рекламу, то мне покажет мою прилу и внутри этой ссылки будет GCLID И ВНУТРИ прилы я уже обрабатываю этот GLCID).НО!
Если юзер нажал на рекламу внутри маркета, то GCLID я не получаю внутри приложения (только  две utm метки в которых значение not_set). Как мне получить GCLID из маркета... Не известно. Пока что.

Answer (score 2):

Похожий вопрос
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743129/google-ads-attribution-in-firebase-sdk/58801441?noredirect=1#comment103922617_58801441

Я убрал receiver из манифеста вместе с соответствующим классом.
После установки через рекламу `getInstallReferrer()` возвращает что-то вроде

```
gclid%3D<ID клика>
```

Почему знак `=` закодирован, не вполне понятно, ведь при установке через традиционные utm_source/utm_medium знаки `&` и `=` в нормальном виде.